# Confused about sending mail

Tags: android

I am trying to send an e-mail with a file attached,So  I have downloaded sample project  and working on it.The problem is everytime I get the same message "couldnt attach file (sorry for my english)
 So far I have this .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText et_address, et_subject, et_message;
String address, subject, message, file_path;
Button bt_send, bt_attach;
TextView tv_attach;

private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
Uri URI = null;
int columnindex;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initializeViews();
    bt_send.setOnClickListener(this);
    bt_attach.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void initializeViews() {
    et_address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_address_id);
    et_subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_subject_id);
    et_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message_id);
    bt_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_send_id);
    bt_attach = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_attach_id);
    tv_attach = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_attach_id);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.bt_attach_id:
        openGallery();
        break;

    case R.id.bt_send_id:

        try {
            address = et_address.getText().toString();
            subject = et_subject.getText().toString();
            message = et_message.getText().toString();

            String emailAddresses[] = { address };

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    emailAddresses);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            if (URI != null)
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);

            startActivity(emailIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        break;

    }

}

private void openGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
            PICK_IMAGE);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        columnindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        file_path = cursor.getString(columnindex);
        // Log.e("Attachment Path:", attachmentFile);
        tv_attach.setText(file_path);
        URI = Uri.parse("file://" + file_path);
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the error message from? Which email app is launched? Did you check that provided URI is not null? Share the stack trace if there is any error displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your processing of the `Uri` returned from the gallery looks overcomplicated. You are taking a `Uri` and processing it to produce a `Uri`.

I think your `onActivityResult()` method should be more like:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        URI = data.getData();
    }
}
```

This is better as it's also not good practice to pass a "file://" Uri to an external application in case the external email application doesn't have access to the file.

Comment: Log.d("Path control--->>","file://" + file_path); this returns file://null

Comment: I don't understand your comment as it appears to have nothing to do with the fix I've given you. Did you try changing `onActivityResult()` to what I've written above?